# .task crashes - Swift 5.5 (iOS 15 Beta 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Not sure if it's an issue with the latest iOS build or if apple has other plans for this, but until now, I was using `.task {}` instead of `.onAppear {}` for my async function and now it's crashing.

Error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

Crashes on the phone (not simulator):

- iOS 15 beta 5 (19A5318f) (I couldn't find any info of being deprecated [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-15-beta-release-notes))

It works on:

- iOS 15 beta 4 (phone)
- Xcode simulator using macOS 12.0 Beta (21A5304g)

Here's a simple snippet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("iOS 15")
            .task {
                print("please work")
            }
    }
}
```

[image]

Any idea what's happening, if this might be a bug or Apple deviating from it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have that version of Xcode to test this out, but did you try the code in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:))? If that also doesn't work, then I think it's probably a bug on their side.

Comment: @Sweeper checking that code..

Comment: @Sweeper I copy pasted the code and it failed. I'll file a bug report. Do you know the link for it by any chance?

Comment: works well for me on macos 12.beta5, xcode 13.beta5, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. tested on iPhone io15, macos12

Comment: Was your iPhone on the latest beta (5)?  In Xcode it works fine, it's on the iphone where it fails @workingdog

Comment: actually my phone shows iOS 15.0, not beta, I think it is the very latest.

Comment: @workingdog check in about if the version is: 19A5318f

Comment: yes it is that version.

Comment: @workingdog I just restarted the phone and it keeps crashing... with the simplest code I pasted above and with apple's example. I don't know...

Comment: I just know it works for me on my iPhone (10) with ios15, older iPad pro ios15 and macos12.

Comment: what if you use this: `.task { await check() }` and  `func check() async { print("\n-----> please work \n") }`

Comment: I use `Task { }`, it seems to be fine.

Comment: @user1046037, does  `.task {print("please work")}` work for you?

Comment: Your code (`.task {print("please work")}`) works fine in `Xcode Version 13.0 beta 5 (13A5212g)`. Can you try beta 5, beta 4 used to crash quite a bit for me, beta 5 seems more stable

Comment: Arturo is finding that it works for him on ios 15-beta4 but not on ios 15.0-beta5.
It works fine for me on ios 15.0 (beta5) on everything. 
Trying to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bug" is not fixed, I still see the same error on my devices, however I found a work around:

Instead of using in a view:

```
.task {}
```

I'm using:

```
.onAppear {
    Task { ... }
}
```

Will update this answer if anything changes. As of Beta 6 the issue remains...

Comment: I noticed your error message do not match what is in your code snippet.
Are you getting the error in the code that you show, or is it in some other code 
that you are not showing? Because the code you show, works for me (and others) with 
the latest os and xcode.

Comment: The code content is different, the SwiftUI code is the same, I mean.. a .task can't change no matter what you put inside lol and like I said, I tried with the simplest form of code, which I put on the example above and it still fails, it's not my content, I even created a new project with a hello world and it fails :/ @workingdog

Comment: I had the crash with .task on Xcode 13 beta 4 but no longer on Xcode 13 beta 5